# SSRS How to Suppress Bookmarks that target dynamically hidden report items

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Problem: Bookmarks that link to hidden report items still link when clicked, but you end up seeing the next visible item.

I have an SSRS report with a summary table (tablix A) that shows Customers Grouped by Parent Customer. The field containing the parent customer is bookmarked.

Then I have a Tablix (tablix B) with charts, again grouped by parent, with a page break for each parent. The Charts are suppressed (hidden using formula in the Visibility property for the Group parentno in tablix B) if there is not enough data to create senseible charts for that parent customer.

How can I disable the "Go to bookmark" action dynamically, or create a null bookmark instead, when I know the bookmark target will be hidden?

The end goal is for this report to export to excel, so I would also like to avoid the error "refrence is not valid" that appears when you click an invalid bookmark in excel.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be not so difficult, although not immediately obvious.
When you go into text box properties,  Action,  and choose Go to Bookmark, you can use an expression to create the bookmark. If your expresion returns the static constant "nothing".. then SSRS will not create a bookmark. So this means you can use the same formula from your target item that decides if your bookmark target item is hidden or not to dynamically bookmark, or not.

Example if your expression for visibility property is

> =IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!BusinessUnit.Value, "getMainData")>1,False,True)

Then the bookmark expression would be

> =IIF(Parameters!AM.Value="ALL",Fields!BusinessUnit.Value,Nothing)